# Could you suggest me some books about Catholic apologetics?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, apologetics, books

I have recently become interested in Catholic apologetics, but I don't know which book to buy to explore the subject. For example, I was thinking of the book "Handbook of Catholic Apologetics: Reasoned Answers to Questions of Faith" by Peter Kreeft. If you know it, would you recommend it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a [list question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/how-should-we-handle-list-questions). This form of question is off topic.

Comment: @KenGraham - Interestingly enough, when Peter Turner posted an answer, he didn't realize the question was off-topic :-)

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator One can notice that Peter Turner’s answer is a ***community wiki answer***, thus he gets no reputation for any upvotes! That in my opinion is the only solution-able way to go here because anyone can add to his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just add two of my favorite books on Catholic Apologetics and set this as a Community Wiki so everyone can chime in.

- Everlasting Man by G.K. Chesterton

  This is the the book that inspired C.S. Lewis to see Christianity as something that might be worth looking into.  It's an apologetic in that it's an answer to H.G. Wells' outline of history.
- [50 Questions for the Natural Law](https://www.christianbook.com/questions-natural-what-need-revised-edition/charles-rice/9780898707502/pd/707501)

  The Natural Law forms a base for Catholic Apologetics, where it seeks to explain theology through philosophy.  The basis for apologetic arguments is philosophy, the Natural Law is not the only philosophy acceptable to Catholics, but it is a subset of the Truth that is very close to everything someone can perceive as true.  This book breaks down how the natural law applies to many of the things someone would want to concoct an apologetic for.  (very useful for this site)
- [The Case for Catholicism: Answers to Classic and Contemporary Protestant Objections](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1621641449) by Trent Horn.

  His is the most up-to-date, comprehensive, and thorough defense of the Catholic Church against Protestant objections in print. This book is especially relevant as the 500th anniversary of the Protestant Reformation draws near and discussion of the arguments made against the Church during that time in history receive renewed interest.

  The Case for Catholicism answers arguments put forward by early Reformers like Luther and Calvin as well as contemporary defenders of Protestantism like Norm Geisler and R.C. Sproul. It provides a meticulous defense of the biblical and historical nature of Catholic doctrines from Scripture and church history. Finally, in both answering Protestant objections to Catholicism and in providing evidence for the Faith,The Case for Catholicism cites modern Protestant scholars who question Reformation assumptions and show how evidence from Scripture and church history support aspects of Catholic theology.

  This book is divided into four sections, with each answering a key question Christians have asked about the nature of their faith. Those key questions are:

  - What is my authority?
  - What is the Church?
  - How am I saved?
  - Who belongs to the body of Christ?

  The Case for Catholicism will become a reliable, resource for any Catholic who desires a well-researched, readable, and persuasive answer to Protestant arguments made against the Catholic faith.

Answer (score 1):

- [*The Principles of Catholic Apologetics*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DWalshe%2C%20Fr.%20T.%20J.%22) by Fr. T. J. Walshe
- [*God: His Existence and His Nature: A Thomistic Solution of Certain Agnostic Antinomies*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=title:%22God:%20His%20Existence%20and%20His%20Nature:%20A%20Thomistic%20Solution%20of%20Certain%20Agnostic%20Antinomies%22) by Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.